# PYTHON Como retornar para um input após um valor inserido não ser válido

Tags: python, algoritmo, loop, if, operador-lógico

de acordo com o enunciado da questão que estou tentando resolver, preciso fazer um programa que leia o valor anual de um locador de serviço e, conforme o plano de assinatura que ele tenha, devolva uma % do valor para o locatário. A princípio acho que me sai muito bem na resolução, porém, gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que, quando o usuário selecione um número que não seja referente a nenhum plano (exemplo 6) apareça a mensagem 'Essa não é uma opção válida' e então retorne para o input 'selecione abaixo o seu atual plano de assinatura [...]' até o usuário digitar um valor válido.

```
annualInvoice = float(input('\nDigite o valor do seu faturamento anual em reais: '))
planType = int(input('\nSelecione abaixo o seu atual plano de assinatura:\n\n [1] Basic | [2] Silver | [3] Gold | [4] Platinum\n\nPlano de assinatura: '))

paymantPercentage = 0

if planType == 1:
    paymantPercentage = annualInvoice * 0.30
elif planType == 2:
    paymantPercentage = annualInvoice * 0.20
elif planType == 3:
    paymantPercentage = annualInvoice * 0.10
elif planType == 4:
    paymantPercentage = annualInvoice * 0.05
else:
    print('Essa não é uma opção válida')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while

Comment: Apesar da resposta abaixo funcionar, eu acho que tem muito código repetitivo e daria para simplificar, algo assim: https://ideone.com/Yg4r5G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o `input` dentro de um loop `while` para este objetivo.

O que vai acontecer no código é o seguinte:

Crie uma variável que possibilite você validar se o plano está dentro das opções ou não. No exemplo, criei uma chamada `planoValido` e defini seu valor inicial como `False`.

Enquanto a variável `planoValido` não for verdadeira, ou seja: não estar nas opções escolhidas, o `while` vai repitir a solicitação de `input` `planType` ATÉ obter uma opção válida. Veja que coloquei em todas as opções válidas um "planoValido = True", justamente para dar um fim à repetição do `while`.

```py
annualInvoice = float(input('\nDigite o valor do seu faturamento anual em reais: '))

planoValido = False
while planoValido == False:
    planType = int(input('\nSelecione abaixo o seu atual plano de assinatura:\n\n [1] Basic | [2] Silver | [3] Gold | [4] Platinum\n\nPlano de assinatura: '))
    if planType == 1:
        paymantPercentage = annualInvoice * 0.30
        planoValido = True
    elif planType == 2:
        paymantPercentage = annualInvoice * 0.20
        planoValido = True
    elif planType == 3:
        paymantPercentage = annualInvoice * 0.10
        planoValido = True
    elif planType == 4:
        paymantPercentage = annualInvoice * 0.05
        planoValido = True
    else:
        print('Essa não é uma opção válida')
```

De qualquer maneira, tem formas mais fáceis de você fazer isso com funções, mas pelo que vi, você está aprendendo, então já já você chega lá.

Comment: Obrigado! Você é um deus e lembrarei de você enquanto viver e codar!!!!